# .NET Library To Convert MS Word Document to XPS Document

Tags: .net, wpf, xps

Does anyone know of a 3rd party library that will convert a Microsoft Word document to an XPS file?

I know this is possible using MS Word or using Word automation, but I would like to have a library to do the converting that does not rely on the computer to have MS Word installed.

I need to do the converting completely in code using an API. There will be no user interaction in the converting process.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do the conversion directly without any 3rd party dll's using Office Interop. Here's an article demonstrating how to view a Word doc as an XPS using WPF *(link to article is now dead and has been removed)*.

From the code presented in the article, converting Word to XPS should be fairly straight forward; ignoring the WPF parts, of course.

**EDIT**

The above answer does require Word; my mistake.

[Apose.Word for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/key-features.aspx) will convert Word to XPS without Office/Word installed. Though it's probably a bit pricey.

Comment: I think he already knew this information and is looking for ways of doing it without using Office Interop.

Comment: @Tony - looks like I missed this one big time. See added edit for 3rd party solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. You are correct, I'm trying to find a solution without Word. I've researched Apose.Word a bit and it seems like its more than I need. Just want a little tool to do the conversion...