# Converting Word Document to XPS Document in C# WPF

Tags: c#, ms-word, wpf-controls, xps

I am working on one application which is using XPS documents. I have word documents and I want to convert all the word documents to XPS documents.

I have one main **Folder** (Instructions) and inside (Instructions) there are many other Folders. Each Folder have so many Word Documents. How can I convert all these **Word Documents to XPS Documents recursively**.

Currently I have this Function which is Converting Word to XPS

```
public static string convertWordToXps(string path, string wordDocName)
    {
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Documents.Open(string.Concat(path, "\\", wordDocName), ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: true);
        string xpsFile = string.Concat(path, "\\", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordDocName), ".xps");

        try
        {
            //wordApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(xpsFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, false, true, WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, false, true, false, nullObject);
            wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
            return xpsFile;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.getDetailedErrorMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            wordApp.Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: Type.Missing, RouteDocument: Type.Missing);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You could start with this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337556/net-library-to-convert-ms-word-document-to-xps-document/18012873#18012873
Then paste your code and ask what u need to.
Nobody will work out a solution for you, you have to put a little effort before asking a question.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik i posted the code. can you post your solution if you knew the solution. The above thread didnt help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an static method that do what you need.

```
static void SearchDocuments(string directoryPath)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string fullName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath,"*.docx")) // if your word documents come from an older version of word, they might have .doc extenstion
            {
                convertWordToXps(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullFileName), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileName));
            }
            foreach (string nestedDirectory in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath))
            {
                SearchDocuments(nestedDirectory);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception error)
        {
            //Do whatever u want on exception
        }
    }
```

Btw. think over if you have reason to use static functions.

Comment: This command is not available because no document is open. 

Error is at this line : 
wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);

Comment: @Muhammadzubair: maybe try to open document not readonly ?

Comment: @Muhammadzubair so instead `wordApp.Documents.Open(string.Concat(path, "\\", wordDocName), ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: true);`

use:

`wordApp.Documents.Open(string.Concat(path, "\\", wordDocName), ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: false);`

Comment: Same Error :( i changed it to False

Comment: @Muhammadzubair paste entire exception you get in the thread topic.

Comment: This command is not availalbe becasue no document is open. at Miscrosoft.office.interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_ActiveDocument at Line 65 which is:

wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240715/discussion-between-muhammad-zubair-and-bartosz-olchowik).